# Eclipse Android error

Tags: android, eclipse

Vista 64; Eclipse 3-5-1.

I'm getting this error when I work on main.xml:

ERROR Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/get_text').

To eliminate variables I've created a new Android Project

1. Opened main.xml and pasted this in
2. When I hit save I get the above error in a red X next to the

This is related to a problem mentioned on this site. It's question # is [885009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885009/).

My project is set to automatically build.

Comment: In your java file, are you importing android.R? If so, remove it.

Comment: Also, make sure your res/values/strings.xml has the following in it
<string name="get_text">The text goes here</string>

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your string.xml

```
<string name="get_text">SAMPLE</string>
```